# Get 'hg import' to use internal:merge

Tags: version-control, mercurial, merge

Right now when I `hg import` a patch, and it fails to apply cleanly, hg partially applies the patch (the hunks that could apply cleanly) and saves the rejected hunks to a `.rej` file.

I find this really annoying to work with. Is there a way to get hg to use `internal:merge` instead when this happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviosuly the `import` command does not have such an option and it seems to ignore any other [merge tool configurations](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MergeToolConfiguration). I can think of 2 work-arounds:

1. Use `hg import --exact` and then merge the import commit with your main head. This only works for patches created with the `hg export` command, i.e. patches with revision information. Then you can make a regular merge of your main head and the new head created by the import.

   ```
   $ hg import --exact foo.patch
   $ hg merge
   ... fix conflicts if needed ...
   $ hg commit -m 'apply patch foo'
   ```
2. Use good old patch command:

   ```
   $ patch -p1 --merge < foo.patch`
   ... fix conflicts if needed ...
   $ hg commit -m 'apply patch foo'
   ```

   This creates in-file markers similar to `internal:merge`.

If these multiple-step solutions are no options for you, think about [requesting a feature](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/BugTracker) to add a `--merge` option to the import command. Alternatively you might glue these commands together in a script so you have your own one-shot import command.

Comment: Typically the patches I apply don't have commit information, so `patch` seems the way to go, and 2 steps would be necessary anyways. Thanks!